# Get Position of a combobox in an Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, position

I have a sheet with comboboxes in it. To the left of the comboboxes there is a column where the user can mark positions with an "X" if the combobox to its right should be doing stuff (filling itself with Values that are taken from a dynamic range). I was thinking of something like this but am not managing to make it work:

```
Dim ComBx As ComboBox
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tool")

For Each ComBx In ws2.ComboBox
    If ComBx.Offset(0, -1).Value = "X" Then
        With ComBx
            'do stuff
        End With
    End If
Next ComBx
```

Any ideas how to reference the position of a combobox anyone? I had to do something similar for checkboxes, where it worked just fine, but this eludes me.

Comment: What sort of ComboBox? ActiveX or the Form control?

Comment: It is an active X combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Combo-boxes type are `Active-X` try the code below.

`ComBx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, -1).Value` returns the value of the cell located one column to the left of the cell where your Combo-Box is located.

**Note**: besides that, you have a **Typo** in your code, you defined and set `ComBx`, but then using `If CmBx.Offset(0, -1).Value = "X" Then` and also closing with `Next CmBx` - this shouldn't even compile.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CmbBoxPosition()

Dim ComBx As OLEObject
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tool")  
For Each ComBx In ws2.OLEObjects
    If ComBx.progID Like "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
        ' for DEBUG Only
        Debug.Print ComBx.Name & " located at " & ComBx.TopLeftCell.Address(False, False, xlA1)
        If ComBx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, -1).Value = "X" Then
            With ComBx
                ' the rest of your code goes here

            End With
        End If
    End If
Next ComBx

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you! I also corrected the type in my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveX combo boxes then you can run this example to see what the 'TopLeftCell' value (or any offset from it) for all your combo boxes are just to be certain you're looking at the right ones.

```
Sub GetCombos()
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim cel As Range

  Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tool")

  For Each shp In ws2.Shapes
    If shp.FormControlType = xlDropDown Then
      Set cel = shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1)
      If cel.Value = "X" Then
        Debug.Print "cell at row=" & cel.Row & " column=" & cel.Column & " has an X in it"
       ' do stuff
      End If
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

If it's not the right one you can change the x and y values of  `shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(x,y)` to the correct offset and update your code accordingly.

Comment: This didn't work for me because of the xldropDown line, but Shai Rados answer did. Thanks for your input non the less!